# how can i write this with javascript (without jquery)

Tags: javascript, jquery

how can i write this with javascript without jquery
i want slideshow move the right with 100% and then append the first child :

she's only moving the right without appending the first child

```
$(document).ready(function ($) {

setInterval(function () {
    moveRight();
}, 3000);

function moveRight() {
    $('#slider ul').animate({
        right: 100
    }, 200, function () {
        $('#slider ul li:first-child').appendTo('#slider ul');
        $('#slider ul').css('right', '');
    });
};
});
```

Here's my code:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {

setInterval(function () {
    moveRight();

}, 5000);

var li = document.getElementsByClassName("image");
var ul = document.getElementById("images");
var len = ul.getElementsByTagName("li").length;
var first = ul.firstChild;

ul.style.width = len + "00%";

function moveRight() {
    ul.style.right = "100%"
    function () {
        ul.appendChild(first)
        ul.style.right = "0%"
    }
}

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your anonymous function isn't being executed.

change:

```
function moveRight() {
    ul.style.right = "100%"
    function () {
        ul.appendChild(first)
        ul.style.right = "0%"
    }
}
```

to:

```
function moveRight() {
    ul.style.right = "100%"
    setTimeout(function () {
        ul.appendChild(first)
        ul.style.right = "0%"
    },200);
}
```

Comment: hi Steve, i tried your code but after sliding 100% she go back to 0% without appending

Comment: that's interesting. Should work. Can you supply the html with this example js?

Comment: ok the problem is you are using css to animate the ul 100%. It works in that it slide the ul to the right by 100%, but as soon as you make javascript change it back to 0%, it animates back again which you don't want.

Comment: can you help me please to fix that problem

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
    function moveRight() {        

        ul.style.transition = "none";
        ul.style.right = "0";
        ul.appendChild(first);          
        first = document.querySelector('#images li:first-child');  

        setTimeout(function () {        
            ul.style.transition = "";
            ul.style.right = "100%";   

            },1000);
        }
}
```